# How to securely share your Amazon wish list with only certain people

Tags: security, sharing, amazon, wish-list

On Amazon is there any way to share wish lists with only certain people? I can make a list public or private and I can share it, but can I make it public to only certain people can see it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As of now, no.  However, the only way other people will see it is if they specifically search for you using your name or email address - If you want it to be private, just change your name to something else, and link only the friends you want to see it using share, and let them know the reasoning behind changing your name so they don't think you're insane.  If you want it really, really private, change your email address associated with the account.

Hopefully Amazon will add a feature like you described in the future.

Answer (score 2):

https://www.amazon.com/gp/help/customer/display.html?nodeId=501094
Public: Anyone can see it.
Shared: Only people with a url/link to your list can see it
Private: Only you can see it